# KSQLDB Create Stream Select AS with Headers

Tags: apache-kafka, stream, ksqldb

Is there a way in KsqlDB to add headers while creating a stream from AS SELECT?

For example, I have a stream DomainOrgs(DomainId INT,OrgId INT,someId INT), now I need to create a stream with all the values in DomainOrgs also DomainId should go to Header

I tried to create like

```
CREATE STREAM DomainOrgs_with_header AS
SELECT DomainId,
       OrgId,
       someId,
       DomainId HEADER('DomainId') 
  FROM DomainOrgs
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

Also tried

```
CREATE STREAM DomainOrgs_with_header
(
   DomainId INT,
   OrgId INT,
   someId INT,
   DomainId_Header Header('DomainId')
)

INSERT INTO DomainOrgs_with_header
SELECT DomainId,OrgId,someId,DomainId FROM DomainOrgs
```

Here, stream will create but INSERT INTO will fail.

Is there any way to select data into the stream with headers?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the Bytes

```
CREATE STREAM DomainOrgs_with_header
(
   DomainId INT,
   OrgId INT,
   someId INT,
   DomainId_Header BYTES Header('DomainId')
)
```

https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/quick-reference/#header